# Problem with unregistered Jet 4.0 on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: c#, windows-7, 64-bit, oledb, jet

I am trying to run a program, running on the hard drive, that uses Microsoft Jet OleDB to open and get info from an MS Access database. The problem is that when I try to run the program Visual Studio gives me this error:

"The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

I tried building the program to target "x86" instead of "Any CPU", but that did not work. I also looked in the Windows\SysWOW64 folder (the 64 bit equivalent to Windows\System32 folder on a 32 bit machine). Both msjet40.dll and msjetoledb40.dll files are in this folder, so I know the files exist. I also tried going to this folder in the command prompt and typing "regsvr32 " for both files. I saw this method used to register DLLs on another website.

My question is how do I get the Jet 4.0 utilities to work on my Windows 7 64 bit machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the SysWOW64 directory is the 32 bit files. If you had a msjet40.dll and msjetoledb40.dll in System32, those would be 64 bit. As far as I am aware, there are no 64 bit versions of Jet around. I could be mistaken as there is a new 64 bit Office coming.

Comment: I hear (but don't know first-hand) that 32-bit "Jet" (in the form of ACE) is in A2010.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the platform to "x86" for the application and all dependencies from the solution level, not the project level.