# Jet OLEDB Provider working everywhere except Excel 2010 on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: excel, windows-7, 64-bit, oledb, jet

I'm using the "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" provider for a basic connection in some VBA code, and the code works everywhere except on windows 7 64-bit operating systems running a 64-bit installation of Microsoft Office Excel 2010.

Literally every other combination of XP 32 or 64, Vista 32 or 64, and 7 32, with Excel 2003, 2007, or 2010 installations has no problem running this code, but on the above described system, it results in an error about a "Missing Provider" and I can't create the connection string.

```
With Conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .Mode = adModeRead
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & path & ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited'"
    .Open
End With
```

I've done a ton of research, but from what I can tell, the operating system is supposed to come with a full set of providers, including the 32-bit version of the Jet Provider (no 64 bit version exists), and Excel should have no problem using it for the connection. Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972015/problem-with-unregistered-jet-4-0-on-windows-7-64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will be helpful to people outside my specific example. I was using the provider to perform a query on a CSV. For instance:

```
SELECT C7, 0.0001, (C2+C4*10000000) FROM (filename)
```

Here, the source file has been modified so that all of the columns are named Cn by their headers:

```
csvColumns = UBound(Split(lineIn, Delimiter)) + 1
For icol = 1 To csvColumns: columnLine = columnLine & "C" & icol & Delimiter: Next icol
```

So in my case, I have a file that looks like this:

```
C1       C2       C3       C4       C5       C6       C7
1234     654332   23.214   5432     12345    123      60918234.234
2345     876332   43.223   6534     23456    234      34958732.432
3456     987332   54.243   7654     34567    345      92645378.564
```

Normally, using the Jet OLEDB provider, the above query string can be used to read the contents of the file into a cell:

```
On Error GoTo PoviderError
With Conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .Mode = adModeRead
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & path & ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited'"
    .Open
End With
Rst.Open "SELECT " & selectText & " FROM [" & file & "];", Conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
If Not Rst.EOF Then Destination.CopyFromRecordset Rst
```

But in the above code "ProviderError" will get triggered on 64 bit machines because there is no Jet provider available. My workaround was as follows. I actually load the file into excel, and parse the query string myself. I break the query string by comma delimiter so that each section of the query string becomes the formula for a new cell. To create the formula, I simply prepend an `=` sign and replace the string "Cn" with a reference to the source column. This way, complex queries like `(C2+C4*10000000)` still get evaluated. I then copy down the formula according to the length of the source data, and then overwrite the formulas with hard coded values. The end result is identical to doing a complex Jet OLEDB query, albeit slightly slower. Code is below.

```
PoviderError:
    Resume FailOver 'Resets the error state so that further errors can be thrown
FailOver:
    FileReadFailover fixedFile, Destination, selectText, Delimiter
    ...

Private Sub FileReadFailover(ByVal fName$, ByRef Dest As Range, ByVal inputs$, ByVal delim$)
    Dim newBook As Workbook
    Dim pos(0 To 2) As Integer, col(0 To 2) As String
    Dim referenceText As String, i As Integer

    'Parse the query string 'inputs'
    pos(0) = 0: pos(1) = InStr(pos(0) + 1, inputs, ","): pos(2) = InStr(pos(1) + 1, inputs, ",")
    col(0) = Trim(Mid(inputs, pos(0) + 1, pos(1) - pos(0) - 1))
    col(1) = Trim(Mid(inputs, pos(1) + 1, pos(2) - pos(1) - 1))
    col(2) = Trim(Mid(inputs, pos(2) + 1))

    Application.StatusBar = Application.StatusBar & " Missing Jet Provider, waiting for Excel to open file..."
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Allow excel to display the status bar showing the file loading
    Application.Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fName, DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:=delim
    Set newBook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If newBook Is Nothing Then Err.Raise 1, , "User Cancelled Load"

    'Create a formula that will pull the values from the external file just opened.
    referenceText = Replace(newBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Address(, , , True), "$A$1", "R[" & 2 - Dest.row & "]C")
    For i = 0 To 2
        If InStr(1, col(i), "C") Then col(i) = "=" & Replace(col(i), "C", referenceText)
        Dest.Offset(0, i).FormulaR1C1 = col(i)
    Next i
    'Copy the formulae down the based on the length of the input file
    Dest.Worksheet.Range(Dest, Dest.Offset(0, 2)).Copy _
        Dest.Worksheet.Range(Dest.Offset(1), Dest.Offset(newBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2, 2))
    'Make sure the worksheet recalculates to pull the values
    If Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual Then Dest.Worksheet.Calculate
    'Now overwrite the formulas that pull the values with the values themselves
    Dest.Worksheet.Range(Dest, Dest.Offset(0, 2).End(xlDown)).Copy
    Dest.Worksheet.Range(Dest, Dest.Offset(0, 2).End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.StatusBar = "File Import Successful"

    newBook.Close (False)
End Sub
```

The above solution assumes a query with 3 columns, but could easily be adjusted to take a any query, use split to get as many columns as there are, and dynamically redim pos() and col() arrays.