# Connection String for Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, office-interop, office-automation

I am using OLEDB to connect to Excel 2010.  What is the required connection string for this operation?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444114/jet-oledb-provider-working-everywhere-except-excel-2010-on-windows-7-64-bit for help and additional issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel):

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
```

or

```
OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
```

Answer (score 1):

That connecting string you posted is for 2003 or older.  Jet will not support 2007 or forward.

Try this instead:

```
 Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
 Data Source = c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
 Extended Properties = "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR ="YES";
```

Or try http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2010/